# ODBC Oracle connector: getSchema for stored procedure parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odbc

I need to retrieve parameter information for Oracle stored procedures, using ODBC connector.
A very simple stored procedure example:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE          TESTPROC(param1 IN INTEGER)
AS
  BEGIN
    //body
  END TESTPROC;
```

Now i want to retrieve parameters information for "TESTPROC".

The first solution I tried was to use the **OdbcCommandBuilder**. I constructed an OdbcCommand with command type: stored procedure, and the command text: procedure name(e.g. TESTPROC). Then I used derive function like this: "**OdbcCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);**"

The problem is that I get an invalid cast exception when calling this function: "Specified cast is not valid."; with stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetInt16(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder.DeriveParametersFromStoredProcedure(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcCommand command)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(OdbcCommand command)
```

The error also reproduces if I declare the parameter type as NUMERIC. 
The weird part is that i can get the correct parameters information if the parameters are of type char or string. It seems that there is a bug when trying to convert Oracle numeric types.

I also tried to obtain the schema for procedure parameters like this, but with no success:

```
string[] restrictions = new string[3];
restrictions[0] = null;
restrictions[1] = null;
restrictions[2] = "MyOwner.TESTPORC";

DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema(OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames.ProcedureParameters, restrictions);
```

Here the problem is that I can't retrieve any rows in the DataTable, and I guess this happens because of the same type conversion problem.

I'd like to find out if there are some workarounds to resolve this issue.
The platform I'm using is Windows 8 x64, and the Oracle client is instantclient_12_1

Comment: I guess this is dotnet code? cSharp ? will help if you mention which.

Comment: Yes, it's .NET. I edited it in C# now